# how to format data to make it time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I want to do time series analysis on the following data
but I can't convert it into time series data,
Data can be downloaded from the given link https://datamarket.com/data/set/22ox/monthly-milk-production-pounds-per-cow-jan-62-dec-75#!ds=22ox&display=line

I have tried `str_split_fixed` function to separate it into two columns but putting back together as a time series after splitting is a problem 
[image: Image of data set]]

This is what I have tried:

```
#Convert it into Time series
#Train Data
ds.ts<-ts(ds$V2,start = c(1962,1),end = c(1974,12),frequency = 12)
ds.ts
plot(ds.ts)
plot(decompose(ds.ts))
#Test Data
ts.1975<-ts(ds$V2,start=c(1975,1),end=c(1975,12),frequency = 12)
```

Comment: I exported a regular CSV version of the data and had a look. I can see nothing that should make it particularly troublesome. Why not show us what you tried and where it went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exported as .tsv (tab separated), but .csv should work as well. Then read to `data.table` and use `substr` to extract the first 4 digits as year (and convert to `integer`) and the last 2 digits as month:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("~/Downloads/monthly-milk-production-pounds-p.tsv")
dt[, ":="(
  year = as.integer(substr(Month, start = 1, stop = 4)),
  month = as.integer(substr(Month, start = 6, stop = 7)))]

>dt
       Month Monthly milk production: pounds per cow. Jan 62 ? Dec 75 year month
  1: 1962-01                                                      589 1962     1
  2: 1962-02                                                      561 1962     2
  3: 1962-03                                                      640 1962     3
  4: 1962-04                                                      656 1962     4
  5: 1962-05                                                      727 1962     5
```

**Updated based on comment by AkselA:**

To obtain a time-series use `as.Date` as suggested by AkselA:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("~/Downloads/monthly-milk-production-pounds-p.tsv")
dt[, date_time := as.Date(paste0(Month, "-01"), format="%Y-%m-%d")]

>dt
       Month Monthly milk production: pounds per cow. Jan 62 ? Dec 75  date_time
  1: 1962-01                                                      589 1962-01-01
  2: 1962-02                                                      561 1962-02-01
  3: 1962-03                                                      640 1962-03-01
  4: 1962-04                                                      656 1962-04-01
  5: 1962-05                                                      727 1962-05-01
```

Comment: You could also deal with the year-month format by simply doing `as.Date(Month, format="%Y-%m-01")`. That way you will get an object of class `Date`, which is much more practical, at least if your goal is a time series.

Comment: That is a much better idea - also since OP wanted a time series. I have updated the answer.